# Why would an AdMob mess with EditText flow and keyboard?

Tags: android, keyboard, admob

I am finishing up an Android calculator app, and I have two versions: free and full. I noticed that in the free version when an ad is displayed in the screen, the flow of the EditText fields doesn't go through all the way down to the last EditText; meaning that when the user hits "NEXT" on the virtual keyboard, the flow breaks when the next field is (I guess) enclosed in another LinearLayout, but it works if the input fields are in the same LinearLayout parent. In the full version, without the ad, it works flawlessly.

In addition, when the user is on the last field, the virtual keyboard shows the "DONE" button; in the free version when this button is clicked, the keyboard goes from a numbers only keyboard (`InputType:number`) to a full keyboard with all it's letters and etc... and doesn't disappear. However, on the full version without the admob, the keyboard simply disappears, as it is suppose to.

I don't know if the location of the admob matters, but this is basically the markup:

```
<LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout>
        <calculator_labels_and_fields>
            Calculator goes here
        </calculator_labels_and_fields>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout>
        The ad from AdMob
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I hope this is clear. I am new to Android dev and am not sure how to approach this very specific behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I figured out a solution, alls I had to do was to explicitly define `nextFocusDown` for each input field and on the last input field, I defined `imeOptions="actionDone"`. Here is a quick example:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_field_1"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:nextFocusDown="@id/et_field_2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_field_2"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:nextFocusDown="@id/et_field_3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_field_3"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

I still don't know why AdMob messes with the flow of inputs, but fortunately I found a solution. It's usually better to define these values anyway, so it's all good.